# Pixelated outline circle

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixelation

I have no Photoshop experience. I am a developer and I am trying to create an outline of a circle, but it always looks pixelated.

I have attached my attempt:

[image]

Can someone please help or point me to a good tutorial? It's driving me crazy, the example was me doing it with canvas to take a screenshot and then using the wand to cut it out. How can I create one with just Photoshop?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi user1503606, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question! It's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve, could you exlpain a bit more? Does the circle itself have to be transparent?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the ellipse tool:

[image: ellipse tool in Ps toolbox]

If you can't find it, it's probably hidden below the Rectangle tool. Press and hold the rectangle to have a series of other tools pop up.

- Draw a circle in your file by dragging with the tool while holding
  <kbd>Shift</kbd>. This will most probably yield a coloured circle
  without an outline.
- Seek out your Layers panel. If you can't find it, check `Window` >
  `Layers` or press <kbd>f7</kbd> to make sure it's present.
- In the layers palette, you'll see a layer named 'Shape 1'. Click it.
- At the top of the layers panel, look for the 'Fill' precentage and set it to 0%:

[image: setting the fill to zero precent]

In this way, you tell Photoshop to hide the layer content while still retaining the Layer style we're going to add.

- Now double-click on the 'Shape 1' layer in the layers panel, anywhere but on the layer's name or thumbnail to pop up the 'Layer Style' dialog box.
- Click the word 'Stroke'. Don't just click the checkmark, click the word.
- Set size, position and colour for your stroke and play away. Commit with 'OK'.

You can change the Shape layer's size and position, and the outline will persist.